# socket.recv(255) in python hung on waiting for data

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth

Newbie question here,

I am trying to hack an existing python program that searches for bluethooth signal

all works fine if there is a bluetooh transmitter around,

but the program simply sits there if there is no Bluetooth signal around.

I found out that it is getting hung on this line

```
    pkt = sock.recv(255)
```

I am naively guessing that is simply sitting there waiting for data,  I want it to give me an error or timeout after lets say 10 seconds.

How do I do this?  Is my thinking correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`settimeout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) before recving. Then it will raise an error if it takes too long.

```
sock.settimeout(10)
try:
    pkt = sock.recv(255)
except socket.error:
    print "connection timed out!"
    return
```

Comment: Kevin, perfect, but now it is  just quitting the program with timeout error without doing the print and return..  I would think the except clause takes care of this

Comment: On second thought, `socket.timeout` is a subclass of `socket.error`, so either one should work. I guess something else is going on. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: pkt = sock.recv(255)
_bluetooth.timeout: timed out

also tried socket.error same thing

Comment: Are there any other lines where you call `sock.recv`? `settimeout` applies to all future `recv` calls, not just the next one, so you'd need to put a try around all of them, or go back to blocking mode using `sock.setblocking(True)`.

Comment: the program quits pointing to that specific line pkt=sock.rev(255)

I tried to give the setblocking a try and various select also but can't get those codes to work.  can you show me how to do this with sock.blocking(True)?

oh do I need any other imports besides these that I have


import errno, sys, struct, socket, os, bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez

Comment: i edited the except line removing socket.error and it worked  Thanks Kevin for your help